# Echoing part of a PHP string back within conditional value of HTML form field

Tags: php, string, forms

I am building an HTML form - a simplified, two field version of which is below. The user is meant to enter something like the below string into the first field of the form:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=12345&link=http%3A%2F
%2Fbit.ly%2F12345&picture=https://website.com/horse-picture.jpg&name=Headline&
description=Description&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2F&
caption=Something
```

I am trying to split this string so that only the following part of the string is echoed into the second field of the form:

```
horse-picture.jpg
```

If the first field is empty, the second field is echoing back its own value. I've marked where the trouble is below. I've seen several threads on using explode, but the part of the string I'm looking to echo back isn't flanked with the same consistent characters, and the length of this string will vary, so preg_match also seems to be not a good option. Having this nested within a conditional is also throwing me off. Would very much appreciate help. Thanks!

```
<h2>THIS IS AN HTML FORM</h2>
<form action="sharefile.php" method="post">

<label for="decode">FB decode:<br /></label>
<input type="text" id="decoder" name="decoder" size="70" value="" /><br /><br />

<label for="img">Image (e.g. horse-picture.jpg):<br /></label>
<input type="text" id="img" name="img" size="70" value="

<?php if (strlen($_POST['decoder']) > 0) 

//THIS IS WHERE THE TROUBLE STARTS
{SOMETHING GOES HERE}
//THIS IS WHERE THE TROUBLE ENDS

else {echo $_POST['img'];}
?>" 


<input type="submit" value="Submit!" name="submit" />

</form>
```

Comment: Go look up [`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php), [`parse_str`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) (and maybe [`basename`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php)) …

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another method. Since this is a URL, first split on the question mark `?` and take the second element, the query string. Now split on the ampersands `&` and loop through them looking for the key/value pair starting with *"picture="*. Once that is found grab the portion of the element after that many characters (8 characters in *"picture="*), then split the string on the forward slash `/` and grab the last element in that resulting array.

If `$_POST['decoder']` equals:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feedapp_id=12345&link=http%3A%2F%2Fbit.ly%2F12345&picture=https://website.com/horse-picture.jpg&name=Headline&description=Description&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2F&caption=Something
```

Then:

```
list($d, $q) = explode('?', $_POST['decoder']);
$pairs = explode('&', $q);
foreach ( $pairs as $value ) {
  if ( !(strpos($value, 'picture=') === FALSE) ) {
    $picture = explode('/', substr($value, 8));
    $picture = $picture[count($picture) - 1];
    break;
  }
}
echo $picture;
```

Outputs:

```
horse-picture.jpg
```

Comment: Thanks! The same comments as above and below - the string will come in as a user-submitted variable, so I can't hardcode it there, and the image file name won't always end in "picture" (but will likely always end in "jpg").

Comment: Right, this code works on dynamic user input; the string is only in the answer for clarification. And this does not rely on "picture" being in the filename. Doesn't rely on ".jpg" either. But it *does* rely on "picture" being the query string variable name, the `picture=` part.

Comment: Hm. Even if I enter your code exactly as written above and use that exact example url as input into field 1, field 2 still remains empty upon submit.

Comment: Okay, I massaged the answer so you can cut and paste it into the HTML form in your question. Try it again.

Comment: Oh great - that works! I kept my "if" bit checking for the string length being greater than 0. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Something like this might work.  I believe you want to parse the picture URL, yes?

```
<?php

function scrub($string) {
        // Parse the picture variable.
        $matches = array();
        $result = preg_match("/picture=([^\&]+)/", $string, $matches);
        $url = $matches[1];

        // Scrub the picture URL.
        $result = preg_replace('/https?:\/\/[^\/]+\//', '', $url);

        print_r($matches);
        print_r($result);
}

scrub("https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=12345&link=http%3A%2F%2Fbit.ly%2F12345&picture=https://website.com/horse-picture.jpg&name=Headline&description=Description&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2F&caption=Something");

/*
Result:

        Array
        (
             [0] => picture=https://website.com/horse-picture.jpg
                 [1] => https://website.com/horse-picture.jpg
        )
        horse-picture.jpg
*/
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! Two things: 1) the url will not always be the same - it will be something like that, but the user will enter something different each time, so hardcoding it into the scrub() won't be an option. 2) the image url won't always end in "picture.jpg" - that was also just an example. It will however likely always end in "jpg". I'm not quite sure how to adjust what you've done to correct for those two things.

Comment: Ugh.  Where do the days go.  The last parts where scrub is called are an example of how it could be used.  You would pass your own URL value into the scrub function, and would have to add a return $result as well.  Meant to give you a decent starting point.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to parse URLs. PHP has functions for that, of course, albeit slightly weird functions, but it's PHP, so we expect that:

```
$url = '.. your massive URL inception ..';

$_url = parse_url($url);
print_r($_url);

parse_str($_url['query'], $query);
print_r($query);

$_url = parse_url($query['picture']);
print_r($_url);

$picture = basename($_url['path']);
var_dump($picture);
```

Example: http://3v4l.org/GKKmq#v430

Comment: Thanks! In my case the "your massive URL inception" will come in as a user-submitted variable in field one ("$decoder"), so I can't plug in a specific url there. The other thing is, this has to execute within the second form field. I altered your suggestion to:                                  $_url = parse_url($decoder);
print_r($_url);

parse_str($_url['query'], $query);
print_r($query);

$_url = parse_url($query['picture']);
print_r($_url);

$picture = basename($_url['path']);
var_dump($picture);

Comment: But this results in a long string

Answer (score -1):

You should do something like this:

```
<?php echo '<input type="text" id="img" name="img" size="70" value="'.$whatyouwant.'"'; ?>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: this isn't related to the question being asked.

Comment: I didn't understand the question. But I thought it were something like that.

Comment: I have this set up within the value="" - it's echoing the value of the second field if the first field isn't submitted. I was asking for help on how to check if the first field had been submitted and if it had, how to parse the submission.